# add a zero after regex target lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list like following:

```
Xbo
Play
Sep2018
/////////////////////////
reregg
95959
1151
Zbo
Tlay
Jul2018
```

Now I want to add a zero between lines before date lines that start with a character and consecutive like following:

```
Xbo
0
Play
0
Sep2018
/////////////////////////
reregg
95959
1151
Zbo
0
Tlay
0
Jul2018
```

I tried following regex but not working:

```
find : (?m)(?:^[A-Za-z].*\R([A-Za-z].*)$\R\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b)|(?<!\A)\G[A-Za-z].*\R)\K
replace : 0\n
```

where is my regex problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex for search:

```bash
(?:^[A-Za-z].*\R\K|(?!^)\G)(?=(?:[A-Za-z].*\R)*(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b)
```

and replace with:

```
0\n
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AB4Lwm/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `^[A-Za-z].*\R\K`: Start with a line that starts with a letter till end of line and then reset the match
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?!^)\G`: Start matching from the end of previous match
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `(?=`: Start positive lookahead

  - `(?:[A-Za-z].*\R)*`: that matches 0 or more lines starting with a letter
  - `(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b`: Followed by Month and 4 digit year
- `)`: End positive lookahead